# WPF DataGrid - How to make selected row editable on Button click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

The following DataGrid is set to `ReadOnly`. But, when `Edit Button` on a row is clicked I need that row to become editable. How can we achieve this task?

Please note that the Edit button click event is still fired on a ReadOnly grid. Maybe, in this event we need to set [DataGridCell.IsEditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.isediting?view=netcore-3.1) Property to true for each cell on that row. But I am not able to get the `DataGridCell object` in the row. Or, there may be some better options.

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        .....
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyDatagrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding MyClassId}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MyClass and other relevant code**:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public int MyClassId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    .........
    .........
}

//DataGrid binding to source:
List<MyClass> lstMyClass = db.MyClass.ToList();
MyDatagrid.ItemsSource = lstMyClass;
............
.........
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="MyDatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" IsChecked="{Binding Is_Checked}"></ToggleButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding MyClassId}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Is_Checked}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Is_Checked}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

First, Each Column Must Have IsReadOnly.

And IsReadOnly Binding MyClass's Is_Checked.

ToggleButton's IsChecked Binding MyClass's Is_Checked,too.

Then, When ToggleButton Click , Change Column's IsReadOnly.

All of this should be MVVM

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public int MyClassId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public bool Is_Checked{ get; set; }
    .........
    .........
}
```

Comment: **Welcome to SO!** Please add some description for your code-- leaving it without description makes it harder to read, and generally defeats the purpose of answering.

Comment: sorry. I don't know English well... I add description

Comment: No worries, just advising :)

Comment: @박석양 Welcome to `Stack Overflow` and thank you for trying to help. I am not using `MVVM`. I am just using [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) with `SQLite` database.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CurrentCell` property to a `DataGridCellInfo` and call `BeginEdit()` if you want to enter the edit mode programmatically:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyDatagrid.IsReadOnly = false;
    MyDatagrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo((sender as Button).DataContext, dataGrid.Columns[0]);
    MyDatagrid.BeginEdit();
}
```

Note that you have to set `IsReadOnly` to `false` to be able to enter the edit mode. You cannot edit a read-only `DataGrid`. You may set it back to `true` in the `CellEditEnding` event handler.

Comment: I do want all the other rows to `stay` in ReadOnly mode `while` the user is editing the selected row and `not after` user is done editing that row. Otherwise, your suggestion does work.

Comment: This shouldn't matter since you can only edit once cell at a time anyway, right? Could you please describe a scenarion where this fails?

Comment: While user should focus on editing the row (s)he clicked the Edit button on, user may by mistake hit some key to end up modifying some cell outside the row (s)he should have focused on. Using a `Save` button, I'm saving the changed data by  
using the `(e.EditingElement as TextBox).Text` value in the `CellEditEnding` event and assigning it to a global variable. Example in the next comment below:

Comment: Example from the above comment: User clicks on `Edit` on third row, made a change there, saw something on fourth row, made a change there but then realized I don't need a change here, went back to third row and clicked on Save button. But code actually had assigned the globabal variable new value from the fourth row. This would be a rare case. But I'm following the traffic rule: Please stay in your line for safety.